# Android HTC phone with two rear cameras

Tags: android, camera, htc-android

I'm trying to select the rear camera in HTC phones but in the API I have only two cameras: [CAMERA_FACING_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT), [CAMERA_FACING_BACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_BACK). When I call the [open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)) with [CAMERA_FACING_BACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_BACK), I get the camera that I don't want (lower resolution than the other one).

Which id should I use to open the other rear camera?

Comment: Ask this question on HTC official forum:)

Comment: I'd suggest trying to pass 3 as camera id.

Comment: ...Or try calling Camera.open() with no parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select the camera directly.

You should open the camera with [CAMERA_FACING_BACK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) and [set a picture size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int%2C%20int%29) (it has 27 possible different sizes!).

Accordingly with picture size you set to the software camera, one of hardware cameras will be the chosen one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35024664/192373. TL;NR: the second sensor facing back will not deliver a conventional image anyway.