# Making use of 2nd rear camera Honor 6+

Tags: android

I need to use both backside Cameras of the Honor 6+ simultaneous. 
But Android sees the 2 Cameras as 1 Single Camera, i think. At least i can't access the 2nd Camera. I can't find anything in the Android API.

Does anybody know or have an Idea how you can access the 2nd Backside Camera ?

Comment: This isn't specific to the Honor 6+, but others have tried it with HTC phones, check out these answers and see if any of that makes sense.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323438/android-htc-phone-with-two-rear-cameras
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216291/htc-one-m8-making-use-of-2nd-rear-camera/35024664#35024664
Lastly, it may not help but you should include code examples of things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link, it might be useful for you.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#getCameraIdList()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this before, but the getCameraIdList shows only 2 Cameras, not 3. The front Camera and one of the backside Cameras.